# Eloquent and mysql casting to boolean not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
  $mm = new MyModel();
  $mm->share_info = 'yes';
  $mm->save();
```

model:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{

    public $table = 'mymodel';

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';



    public $fillable = [
        'share_info',
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'share_info' => 'boolean',
    ];
```

result column, is boolean tinyint in mysql.

**Result is 0 in DB instead of 1.**

**Why?**

```
  $mm->share_info = true;
```

does work as expected

Comment: Why are you trying to save the `string` value of `'yes'` to a `tinyint` field?

Comment: tinyint is the official representation of boolean by eloquent for mysql. You create a boolean this way `$table->boolean('share_info');` the result is a column tinyint. There is no boolean in mysql.

Comment: Yes I know that, so why are you setting a `boolean` column as `'yes'` (which is a `string`) and not `1, 0, true, false`? Are you expecting the model to know that `'yes'` should equal `1` or `true`? Cause I don't think it works that way...

Comment: 2017... you get the values by forms mostly as strings. Is it my job to do the conversion in 2017? I recommend you this article https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-eloquent-attribute-casting#what-is-attribute-casting

Comment: `$model->share_info = strtolower($value) == "yes" ? 1 : 0;` That's not that hard lol...

Comment: that is a plaster solution. E.g. "I dont understand how it works, i'll just manually and repetitively fix it each time I write to a boolean field, for all boolean fields, and for all other fields I fail to understand too." This solves the symptom, not the issue.

Comment: and better is obviously using a laravel / eloquent mutator instead of doing the manual work each time for that field

Comment: You're correct, which is why I'm writing this all as comments, and not an answer. I don't know the solution, all I was trying to do was discern what you were trying to accomplish. Keep in mind, casting a `string` to `boolean` like describe in your linked article can cause issues. `echo (bool)"no";` will return `1`, so I'm not sure how well that approach will work anyway.

Comment: yes you are correct, I am using the mutator for now with a call to `filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` which seems more like what one might want. But it doesnt work in the first place, which surprised me

Comment: Maybe look at changing your question. Laravel casting to boolean is working, its just you are trying to filter your input which makes the string 'yes' a boolean output. What you could do is make a check in your Request (If you're using Laravels requests). Use an if statement in the request which changes the output to a boolean based on if the string is 'yes or 'no'

Comment: @ChrisTownsend how is laravel casting to boolean working if it does not cast 'whatever' to true?

Comment: The casting is used for integers, so casting a 0 or 1 to a Boolean. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting. Not strings

Comment: so the casts happen when "accessing" the attributes. With "Access" only read is meant?

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this by laravel magic methods for setting/getting attributes:

```
public function setShareInfoAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['share_info'] = (int) $value == 'yes';
}

public function getShareInfoAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['share_info'] ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```